# Proof that function is pseudoconvex

Tags: functional-analysis

Proof that $f:R \rightarrow R, f(x)=x^3+x$ is pseudoconvex

Definition of pseudoconvex: $\nabla f(x)^{\top}(y-x)\geq0\implies f(y)\geq f(x)\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

My attempt:

$$\nabla f(x)^{\top}(y-x)=(3x^2+1)(y-x)=(3x^2y+y)-(3x^3+x)\geq0$$
$$(3x^2y+y)\geq(3x^3+x)$$
which is different from$f(y)\geq f(x)$

where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(3x^2+1)(y-x)\geq 0$ implies $y\geq x$ because $$(3x^2+1)>0$$

for all real $x$, thus $$y^3+y\geq x^3+x $$

because $f(x)=x^3+x$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: omg, I'm an idiot, it was obvious. Thank you!